# Cant open the followers button on Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I try to  click followers button on Instagram but nothing seems to be working.The error is

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"followers"}"
```

I tried as `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("followers").click()`.

Help me please :(

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='-nal3 ']").click()
```

(You have to are in a profile url)

Comment: It didn't work. I tried the samething but still ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='-nal3 ']"}```